# Win10 Reset App

Tags: windows-10, powershell

We use a particular APP on our Win-10 machines and upon occasion, the APP fails to work properly. This is the Xodo App if it matters. To fix this my users select "Advanced options" from Settings->Apps followed by clicking on Reset.

I'd like to simply do this on schedule from Task Manager but cannot find a command line to reset this App.

Does anyone have Powershell command advice to reset a user's installed APP?

Comment: It is probably more difficult and time consuming to use powershell (only other method) than just resetting the app normally. That only takes seconds. https://winaero.com/reset-a-store-app-in-windows-10-using-powershell/

Comment: @John - The querent specifically wants to do this from a scheduled task, rather than strictly at need; this is probably to avoid the need (and probably also short-circuit calls to the Help Desk).

Comment: Why are you writing 'app' with all capital letters?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an AppX package, you can use the [`Reset-AppXPackage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/reset-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet in Windows build 20215 or later. You will need to know the package name of the package, which is not always obvious; you may be able to determine it using [`Get-AppXPackage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps). See [this page at WinAero](https://winaero.com/reset-a-store-app-in-windows-10-using-powershell/) for an illustrated explanation.

If it’s not an AppX package, you’ll have to consult the app’s documentation.

Comment: An excellent and apparently correct answer but my builds tend to not be high enough.

Comment: @BigMikeL - You can probably achieve the same outcome by uninstalling and reinstalling the application provided you get the package around.

Comment: @BigMikeL - 20215 is an Insider build from mid-September of 2020. I misinterpreted something I read to mean that it was actually the 20H2 release build, so the cmdlet may not actually be generally available yet.